# How can we move to previous screen when action performed

Tags: android

I am new to android...I want to move back to the previous screen when i pressed some button in current screen..how can we implement? ...
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

To end the current activity and go to the previous activity you can just call `finish()`

Answer (score 2):

Within the onClickListener for the button you put `finish();`

Answer (score 0):

If preserving the state of the first activity **not important** you can just create an Intent and just call the first activity. Here how you can do that.Do this at second activity which will call the first one.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent();         myIntent.setClass(getApplicationContext(),NameOfTheFirstActivityClass.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```